# How to run a silent mode batch script command in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, cmd

I have a *.bat* file that I am using to run a .Msi in silent mode. Now I wanna run that batch script command from vb.net. I tried using `process.start()`. Using `process.start()` opens the files, But the issue is the batch script is not executed and .Msi is not installed.I tried executing the same command directly from cmd and it worked.

Now, Can someone help me how I can execute that command form vb.net.(Can someone help me Write that command to the cmd window after starting the cmd process from vb.net). I tried using `standardinput.Writeline()`, It is opening the .txt files, But it is not working for executing the commands for installing the .Msi file.

```
       Dim command As String="@ echo off msiexec /i 
    ""C:\Users\tparvathaneni\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\bin\Debug\SetupProject1.msi"" /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress echo pause >NUL shutdown.exe /r/t 000"
    Dim proc As New ProcessStartInfo
    proc.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    proc.RedirectStandardInput = True
    proc.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    proc.CreateNoWindow = True
    proc.UseShellExecute = False
    Dim pr As New Process 
    pr.StartInfo = proc
    pr.Start()
    pr.BeginOutputReadLine()      
    pr.StandardInput.WriteLine(command)
```

Comment: I think setting `CreateNoWindow` to `True` on your `ProcessStartInfo` should do the job, given that you have `UseShellExecute` set to `False`.

Comment: Setting CreateNoWindow = true helps me prevent the cmd pop-up. Thank You. But I have one more issue executing the batch script i.e., my command in the code I provided.

Comment: You need to separate each command with an `Environment.NewLine` (e.g. `"@echo off" & Environment.NewLine & "msiexec /i (...)" & Environment.NewLine` etc. Note that you need to schedule (/r (or /g) /t [Seconds]) the shutdown, otherwise it will execute immediately after launching the installer. The "pause" thing does nothing. Execute "cmd.exe" with Arguments (in `ProcessStartInfo`) "/k" or "start /WAIT".

Comment: ...or, use `"WAITFOR /T [Seconds] InstallComplete" & Environment.NewLine`. This will insert a wait timeout for the given signal for the amount of seconds specified. + The last batch command should be `"exit" & Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to the commands as arguments  `proc.Arguments =""@echo off" & Environment.NewLine & "msiexec /i" + command + "& Environment.NewLine &" /qn" & Environment.NewLine & REBOOT=ReallySuppress" ` OR can I add them directly as a single command.

Comment: You can link those string to have a single command. But you have to separate the different Commands with an `Environment.NewLine`, not the Command parameters. For example "/qn" is a parameter of `msiexec`. It has to be in the same line (i.e. `"msiexec /i ""[.msi File Path]"" /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress" & Environment.NewLine`). I assume that `REBOOT=ReallySuppress` is a `msiexec` Property value, here. In order to restart after the installation, you could also use the `msiexec` switches `/promptrestart` or `/forcerestart`. So you don't need to handle it yourself (unless you have reasons for it).

Comment: I tried it this way.But it not updating my files.I tried running the same batch script in command prompt directly  and it is not working. I think the way I execute the batch script in command prompt is the issue here. When I run the .bat file (that contains the batch script) directly the files are getting updated, But the same batch script is not updating the files when I execute the script directly in cmd as admin. Could you please suggest me any other way to execute the batch script from vb.net or the correct way to execute it using cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing this into your VBS will launch the batch script without a window or tray icon. This may be an easier way than trying to send commands to your batch window.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Temp\YourFile.bat" & Chr(34), 0
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I am trying to run the batch script with out the command prompt pop-up. And the code you provided is not doing anything at-least for me. Is there any other way to do this.